# Problemas com ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: c#, response

Minha função btnDownloadArquivos_Click bem resumida.

```
protected void btnDownloadArquivos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + nomeArquivo);
            Response.CacheControl = "Private";

           //Aqui dentro tem uma outra função qualquer.


            Response.Flush();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

            EscreveErroNaTela();

}
```

Dentro da função EscreveErroNaTela() tem o seguinte código.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "Alerta", "alert('Alguns arquivos não puderam ser baixados. Clique no botão erros para maiores informações');", true);
```

Esse código ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock funciona bem, o problema é que na função btnDownloadArquivos_Click tem algumas condições, e ao entrar nessa condição ele preenche algumas propriedades do Response, depois da um Flush, Clear, Clear content.

Quando ele preenche essas propriedades o meu ScriptManager não funciona, não é exibido nenhum alerta, o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, seu problema não está nas instruções:

```
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

        EscreveErroNaTela();
```

O que de fato está ocorrendo é quando você adiciona o Header **"Content-Disposition"="attachment..."**, e altera o **"Content-Type"="application/octet-stream"**.

Isto faz com que seu browser trate a resposta de uma maneira diferente, ou seja, ele irá recarregar sua página através do cache, e a sua resposta ele irá tratar como um download, ou seja, ele não interpretará como uma resposta html.

Se realizarmos um trace no próprio browser podemos ver isso mais claramente:
[image: Request Disposition]

Note que no Response Header temos o Content-Disposition como um anexo.

[image: Requisição Vazia]

Já nesta imagem, como você pode ver no detalhe do Response não há conteúdo algum.

Agora perceba o que acontece quando removemos o ***header*** e ***content-type*** do ***response*** obtemos um response diferente:
[image: Imagem sem o header e conent-types mencionados]

Perceba na imagem que já não contamos com o header nem o content-type informados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note também que nosso response agora vem preenchido com o conteúdo html resultado do processamento no servidor.

Para que você possa obter o resultado desejado, você terá um trabalho adicional de tratar em duas requisições.