# C# - Problemas com ScriptManager após Response

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, itextsharp

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Comprovante.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);.
-- código de envio de e-mail e baixa de pdf
Response.Write(pdfDocParc);
```

Basicamente tenho isso em um botão salvar, e após isso tento gerar um alert de alterações salvas:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Test", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Alerações salvas com sucesso!');</script>");
Buscar(); -- método que atualiza a página com as alterações salvas
```

Porém não estou conseguindo, ele passa pela linha e não gera nada, apenas o download do pdf. Vi algo assim nessa pergunta: [Problemas com ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184595/problemas-com-scriptmanager-registerclientscriptblock?answertab=active#tab-top)

Mas não consegui entender como posso resolver.

Alguém teria uma solução?

Comment: No `WebForms` um download precisa ser executado através de um `PostBack`. De forma simples, isso significa que sua `response` só vai retornar o documento e nada mais.

Comment: Sim, ele está retornando o documento certo, realizo também um envio de e-mail junto. Porém após a parte do download, não consigo atualizar a página com o método, passa por ele porém não faz nada.. Nem o alert é acionado, só realiza o download realmente.

Comment: Isso, por isso comentei que vai retornar só seu documento e nada mais. Não adianta registrar nada no `ScriptManager` que isso não vai voltar na `response`... Se quiser fazer isso, vai ter que mudar sua abordagem.

Comment: Há muito tempo atrás contornei isso em um projeto WebForms, abrindo o documento em uma pop up (muito tempo mesmo)... talvez abrindo em uma nova aba você consiga o mesmo contorno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você envia um documento para download para o usuário, você não pode misturar as informações na sua `response`.
Isso significa que você não pode ter parte da resposta sendo um documento e outra parte HTML.

Por isso a parte em que você programou para "atualizar" a página não funciona.
Esse atualizar a página, no final das contas é `HTML` e sua resposta do HTTP é um documento.

É possível sim, fazer o download e atualizar a página, mas você teria que mudar a sua lógica.
Atualizando a página primeiro e fazendo o download depois... Isso pode ser feito de diversas formas...

**Solução 1:**

Esta solução basicamente seria utilizar as funções mais recentes dos navegadores, que permitem que você tenha uma `anchor` com um documento em `base64` e ao "clicar" nesta anchor seria feito o download.

Se aproveitando dessa função, poderiamos fazer o seguinte: Atualizamos essa `anchor` no servidor e depois simulamos um clique nela.

> .aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppDownload" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" />
        <a id="download" runat="server" href="" download="" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> CodeBehind

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string arquivo = @"C:\temp\testes.pdf";

    download.Attributes["href"] = $"data:application/pdf;base64, {Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(arquivo))}";
    download.Attributes["download"] = "teste.pdf";

    //Aqui o script simularia o clique naquela anchor que mencionou antes
    string script = "setTimeout(function(){ alert('Funcionou!');  $get('" + download.ClientID + "').click(); },2000);";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "download_script", script, true);
}
```

**Solução 2:**

Atualizar a página e depois fazer uma requisição para própria página indicando onde está o documento para download através de parâmetros:

> .aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppDownload" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> CodeBehind

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Aqui o script simularia o clique naquela anchor que mencionou antes
    string script = "setTimeout(function(){ alert('Funcionou!');  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?' + 'download=1'; }, 2000);";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "download_script", script, true);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Params?["download"] == "1")
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\temp\testes.pdf";
        FileInfo myfile = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (myfile.Exists)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
            Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

**Solução 3:**

Simular a solução 2, só que ao invés de fazer na própria página, fazer isso com um `IFrame`:

> .aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppDownload" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" />
        <iframe id="downloadFrame" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> CodeBehind

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Aqui o script simularia o clique naquela anchor que mencionou antes
    string script = "setTimeout(function(){ alert('Funcionou!');  $get('" + downloadFrame.ClientID + "').src = window.location.pathname + '?' + 'download=1'; }, 2000);";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "download_script", script, true);
}
```